# Create new build pack

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I need to create new build-pack and I wonder if there is a way to build new BP which inherit or extend other build packs?(for example extend nodeJS build-pack)
I didn't find example for it,so i need your help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Buildpacks cannot inherit from existing buildpacks. However, all the existing buildpacks are [open-source](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/). You can simply fork an existing buildpack, modify the shell scripts and point the application manifest to your buildpack source code repository.

There are lots of tutorials about building custom buildpacks that can get you started.

Here's [one](http://jamesthom.as/blog/2015/03/04/cloud-foundry-custom-buildpacks/) about modifying the NodeJS runtime to include a custom C library.

Answer (score 2):

There is the concept of a multi-buildpack. You specify this when creating the app and then the additional buildpacks in the `.buildpacks` file.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi